# Java graphics programming draw image error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors, scope

Hello I'm getting an error drawing an image onto my frame. I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Im getting the following error here.

```
Java: 77: cannot find symbol
symbol: variable image
location: class DrawComponent
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);


class DrawComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // draw a circle with the same center
        double centerX = 250;
        double centerY = 180;
        double radius = 20;

        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        circle.setFrameFromCenter(centerX, centerY, centerX + radius, centerY + radius);
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.draw(circle);

        String filename = "SydneyOperaHouse.jpeg";
        try{
            Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        }catch(IOException ex){
            // Handle Exeption
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 5):

A few points.

1. **To address the problem of the attribute scope.**  The `image` attribute should be handed to (or loaded in) the constructor and stored as a class attribute that is visible to the paint method. *Never try load images (or do other potentially long running tasks) in this method.*
2. An image for BG will typically be an embedded resource by the time of deployment, so access it by URL.
3. A `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver` so `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be 

   `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`
4. I suspect the image drawing at 0x0 should precede (be done before) drawing the red ellipse, or it will draw over the top of it.

Here is an example based on an image of Sydney (no, not the bloody opera house - fussy, fussy..).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

public class DrawComponent extends JComponent {

    private Image image;

    DrawComponent(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        Dimension d = new Dimension(image.getWidth(this),image.getHeight(this));
        this.setPreferredSize(d);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // always call super first, to get borders etc.
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // paint the BG
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

        // draw a circle with the same center
        double centerX = 250;
        double centerY = 180;
        double radius = 20;

        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        circle.setFrameFromCenter(centerX, centerY, centerX + radius, centerY + radius);
        g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.draw(circle);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "http://pscode.org/media/citymorn1.jpg";
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(s));
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JComponent gui = new DrawComponent(image);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for all the points. Perhaps you should add that solving point 1 also solved his scope problem

Answer (score 3):

You simply declare your image variable in the try block... It is not visible outside it.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
}catch(IOException ex){
    // Handle Exeption
}

g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

The [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/scope.html) of the variable `image` is wrong. Note that you are declaring the variable inside the `try`-block. The variable doesn't exist outside of the `{ ... }` of the `try`-block.

Declare the variable outside the `try`-block:

```
Image image = null;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
} catch(IOException ex) {
    // Handle Exeption
}

if (image != null) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

By the way, you should not be doing I/O inside the `paintComponent` method. It's better to load the image somewhere else (when the application starts up, for example), store it in a member variable, and use it inside the `paintComponent` method.

When you load the image in the `paintComponent` method, it's going to load it every time the component needs to be painted. This will make your application slow.

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect here in the case of an exception ?

```
    String filename = "SydneyOperaHouse.jpeg";
    try{
        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    }catch(IOException ex){
        // Handle Exeption
    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

You should declare/initalise *and* draw within the `try{}` block.